# How Can I run two versions of Sonatype Nexus on the same machine?

Tags: nexus, sonatype

so i just started working on a project, and my task is to upgrade sonatype nexus 1.9.x running on CentOS6 to 2.11.x. The old version is currently deployed via a war file. The goal is to get the new version deployed while not breaking builds when devs try to build their project.

My plan of attack is to download nexus. Make the current nexus that is deployed via tomcat, run on a different port, make the new nexus run on the current port, then proxy the old nexus.

Im running into a couple problems though. the old nexus uses java 1.6. If update java to 1.8, would this break the current running nexus?

Would I be able to run two version of nexus on the same vm? If so, how would i do that and minimize the change of messing something up?

Thanks everyone. Im just starting out and this is all very new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you Nexus install is very old you have to consider your options:

1. You could upgrade the existing instance. 1.9 is VERY old so you have to upgrade in multiple steps. First to 2.0, then 2.7 and then 2.11. This is necessary due to data storage changes for configuration and removed upgrade steps.
2. You could just reconfigure a new server from scratch with the same configuration in terms of repositories and other things and simply rsync the repsitories over to the new storage. You really only have to do this for hosted repositories since the proxy repositories will hopefully still be online and you will just download whatever is requested anew.

If your setup is not too complex I would personally go with option 2. It gives you a chance to revisit things and clean up your setup.

For that setup the steps are roughly.

1. Install Java 8 in parallel to Java 6
2. Install Nexus 2.11 from the bundle so it runs with Eclipse Jetty. Do NOT try to run on Tomcat.
3. Configure it to run on port 9081 or some other non-conflicting port with your original setup and do all the other config including creating the repositories as desired as well as security setup.

Now you should be able to have both servers running.

4. Create a script that rsyncs the repositories (located in sonatype-work/nexus/storage) and run it with the new server offline
5. Start the new Nexus in parallel and run a number of tests against it.

Once you have confirmed everything is working plan for a specific time for the cutover and do this

6. Disable any deployment to Nexus (CI servers, tell people, switch hosted repositories to read only)
7. Run the rsync script one last time
8. Turn the old Nexus server off
9. Configure the new server to use the port of the old one
10. Start the new one up

You are done. Everything should be good now so the last step is to delete the old Nexus and Tomcat setup.

There are various variations for this process of course. Here are some [tips for the rsync.](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21451383-How-to-Back-up-Nexus-for-Active-Standby-Failover)

Also feel free to ping us on the [mailing list or chat](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/lists-live-chat-and-other-resources/) for further help and check out the [comprehensive documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/index.html) as well.